# How to calculate the rate of consumption of aluminium with hydrochloric acid?

Tags: kinetics

> An experiment is done to determine the rate of the following reaction:
>   $$\ce{2 Al (s) + 6 HCl (aq) -> 3 H2 (g) + 2 AlCl3 (aq)}$$
>
> The following data is collected: 
>   \begin{array}{rr} 
> \text{time}/\pu{s} & (\text{Mass of beaker + contents})/\pu{g}\\\hline
>    0.0 & 270.230\\
>   30.0 & 270.200\\
>   60.0 & 270.170 \end{array}
>
> Calculate the rate of consumption of $\ce{Al}$ in $\pu{g/min}$.

The answer is $\pu{0.534 g/min}$, but I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Hydrogen is generated, while aluminium metal is consumed.  The hydrogen escapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since one of the products is a gas $\ce{H2}$, the decrease in system mass must reflect the escape of hydrogen. Thus, after thirty seconds, the system has lost $\pu{0.030 g}$ of hydrogen, which is $\pu{0.01488 mol}$ of $\ce{H2}$.

Thus, the rate $r$ of hydrogen production is:

$$
r (\ce{H2})
= \frac{\Delta n(\ce{H2})}{\Delta t}
= \frac{\pu{0.01488 mol}}{\pu{30 s}}
= \pu{4.96E-4 mol//s}$$

Now, how can you use this rate and the stoichiometry of the reaction to determine the rate of aluminum consumption?

> $\ce{2 Al (s) + 6 HCl (aq) -> 3 H2 (g) + 2 AlCl3 (aq)}$
>  For every three moles of hydrogen produced two moles of aluminium are consumed, therefore $r(\ce{Al}) = -\frac{2}{3}r(\ce{H2}) = \pu{3.31E-4 mol//s}$.